# How to align buttons to text in a table row in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT:** I couldn't solve the problem so I removed the bootstrap classes and have made all buttons on my own so now they are aligned perfectly and it seems like the bootstrap classes were messing things up

How can I align different `td` in a `tr` in a HTML table. Here you can find the screenshot of what I am trying to say: [Image of different elements that I want to vertically align in a `tr` element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFiey.png)

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

This `tr` is generated by js. Code:

```
let itemRow = document.createElement('tr');

        

    let item1 = document.createElement('td');
            let item2 = document.createElement('td');
            let item3 = document.createElement('td');
            let item4 = document.createElement('td');
            let item5 = document.createElement('td');
            let item6 = document.createElement('td');
            let btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
            let btnEdit = document.createElement('button');
        item1.innerHTML = bookTitle;
                item2.innerHTML = author;
                item3.innerHTML = recipient;
                item4.innerHTML = dateIssued;
                btnRemove.className = 'btn btn-outline-danger btn-remove';
                btnRemove.textContent = 'X';
                btnEdit.className = 'btn btn-outline-success btn-edit';
                btnEdit.textContent = 'Edit';
                
        
                itemRow.appendChild(item1);
                itemRow.appendChild(item2);
                itemRow.appendChild(item3);
                itemRow.appendChild(item4);
                item6.appendChild(btnEdit);
                item5.appendChild(btnRemove);
                itemRow.appendChild(item6);
                itemRow.appendChild(item5);
                list.appendChild(itemRow);
```

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: i can see you're using bootstrap, so why you are not using bootstrap margin and padding ?

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman How can I?

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using ?

Comment: read more about [margin and padding in Bootstrap v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic table, without any padding should be vertically aligning everything by default.

It looks like you may have to undo/override any CSS thats being applied to your markup, either with your own CSS or the one from Bootstrap, as @burham noticed you are using it.

This is a very simple fiddle example with each `<td>` being 80px in height to show the 'natural' vertical alignment of a table.
https://jsfiddle.net/pzm6ktv5/

Comment: Actually I have removed all the bootstrap classes altogether and made my own buttons so they don't looks as good but the alignment is perfect,

Comment: great :)

With Bootstrap, if you still want to use their styling, you should still be able to use the button classes without any other previous BS classes in the elements before it.

The only issue you may find is that they might have a different `display:` than the default or some other CSS that is making them not vertically align, in which case you can override those with your own CSS.